# Android OpenCV Highgui.imread wrong color

Tags: android, opencv

i have code to load image from sdcard and post it to ImageView.

```
Mat mRgba = Highgui.imread(dir);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);
mImage.setImageBitmap(bmp, true, null, 5.0f);
```

the image is loaded but it's wrong color. Color seem to be inverted (but not inverted). 
Here is [image comparison](http://ns0.upanh.com/b3.s32.d1/88405aa84dad1f9da7034e9dfbb03921_51486410.ml0001.jpg)

I tried to load image by

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dir);
```

It worked correctly. But i have to use `Highgui.imread`.

What wrong with my code?

Comment: The image comparison link seems to be broken at the moment...

Comment: The default channel order in OpenCV is BGR while Android normally stores images in RGB order. Probably that is your problem.

Comment: @Andrey Kamaev: Thank you. That's all i need. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use something like this:

```
    Mat inputImage = Highgui.imread(pathToFile);
    Mat tmp = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputImage, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);

    Bitmap imageToShow = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.cols(), tmp.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, imageToShow);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load a bitmap supposing that the image is 8-bit/color RGBA: are you sure of that?

Answer (score 0):

Also note that ARGB is not RGBA. You may need to re-arrange the bytes of each pixel. Something like

```
int pixel = get_the_pixel();
int alpha = 0xff & pixel;
pixel = pixel<<8 | alpha;
set_the_pixel(pixel);
```

You'll want to do something more efficient than accessor methods shown here, but you get the idea.